# Error EXC_BAD_ACCESS in list with SmartPointer

Tags: c++, macos, qt, memory-leaks, smart-pointers

I'm facing this problem when I remove an element from my list.

Here my list.h:

```
class AwesomeList {
friend class Iteratore;
private:
class Nodo;

class SmartPointer {
public:
    Nodo* punt;

    SmartPointer(Nodo* n = 0): punt(n) {}
    SmartPointer(const SmartPointer& ptr): punt(ptr.punt) {}
    ~SmartPointer() {
        delete punt;
    }

    SmartPointer& operator=(const SmartPointer& ptr) {
        if (this != &ptr) {
            delete punt;
            punt = ptr.punt;
        }
        return *this;
    }
    bool operator==(const SmartPointer& ptr) const {
        return ptr.punt == punt;
    }
    bool operator!=(const SmartPointer& ptr) const {
        return ptr.punt != punt;
    }
    Nodo* operator->() const {
        return punt;
    }
    Nodo& operator*() const {
        return *punt;
    }
};

class Nodo {
public:
    T* value;
    SmartPointer next;

    Nodo(T* t = T(), const SmartPointer& ptr = SmartPointer()): value(t), next(ptr) {}
};

SmartPointer head;
SmartPointer tail;

public:
class Iteratore{
    friend class AwesomeList;
private:
    AwesomeList::SmartPointer punt;
public:
    bool operator==(const Iteratore& it) const {
        return it.punt == punt;
    }
    bool operator!=(const Iteratore& it) const {
        return it.punt != punt;
    }
    Iteratore& operator++() {
        if(punt != 0) punt = punt->next;
        return *this;
    }
    Iteratore& operator++(int) {
        if(punt != 0) punt = punt->next;
        return *this;
    }
    T* operator*() const {
        if (punt != 0) return punt->value;
    }
};

AwesomeList(const SmartPointer& ptr = 0): head(ptr), tail(0) {
    if (head != 0) {
        SmartPointer p = head;
        while (p != 0)
            p = p->next;
        tail = p;
    }
}
AwesomeList(const AwesomeList& list): head(list.head), tail(list.tail) {}

AwesomeList& operator=(const AwesomeList& list) {
    head = list.head;
    tail = list.tail;
}

int getSize() const {
    int count = 0;
    SmartPointer p = head;
    while (p != 0) {
        p = p->next;
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
bool isEmpty() const {
    return getSize() == 0;
}
T* at(int pos) const {
    if (pos > -1 && pos < getSize()) {
        SmartPointer p = head;
        while (pos--) {
            p = p->next;
        }
        return p->value;
    } else return 0;
}
void add(const T& t) {
    if (head == 0) {
        head = SmartPointer(new Nodo(&(const_cast<T&>(t))));
        tail = head;
    } else {
        tail->next = SmartPointer(new Nodo(&(const_cast<T&>(t))));
        tail = tail->next;
    }
}
void remove(int pos) {
    if (pos > -1 && pos < getSize()) {
        SmartPointer newHead = head;
        SmartPointer p = newHead;
        head = 0;
        while (pos--) {
            add(*p->value);
            p = p->next;
        }
        p = p->next;
        while (p != 0) {
            add(*p->value);
            p = p->next;
        }
    }
}
void replace(int pos, T* t) {
    if (pos > -1 && pos < getSize()) {
        SmartPointer p = head;
        while (pos--)
            p = p->next;
        p->value = t;
    }
}
void replace(int pos, const T& t) {
    if (pos > -1 && pos < getSize()) {
        SmartPointer p = head;
        while (pos--)
            p = p->next;
        T& t_obj = const_cast<T&>(t);
        p->value = &t_obj;
    }
}

Iteratore begin() const {
    Iteratore it;
    it.punt = head;
    return it;
}
Iteratore end() const {
    Iteratore it;
    it.punt = 0;
    return it;
}
T* operator[](const Iteratore& it) const {
    return it.punt->value;
}
};
```

This are the tests I made:

```
AwesomeList<int> list = AwesomeList<int>();
list.add(1);
list.add(2);
list.add(3);
for (int i = 0; i < list.getSize(); i++)
    qDebug() <<*(list.at(i)) <<" ";

list.remove(-1);
for (int i = 0; i < list.getSize(); i++)
    qDebug() <<*(list.at(i)) <<" ";

list.remove(2);
for (int i = 0; i < list.getSize(); i++)
    qDebug() <<*(list.at(i)) <<" ";

list.replace(0, 5);
qDebug() <<"Replace in posizione 0";
auto cit = list.begin();
for (; cit != list.end(); cit++)
    qDebug() <<*(*cit) <<" ";

qDebug() <<"Size";
qDebug() <<list.getSize() <<endl;
```

This is the lines where errors appears:

- AwesomeList::Nodo::~Nodo() + 16 (awesomelist.h:8)
- AwesomeList::SmartPointer::~SmartPointer() + 42 (awesomelist.h:21)
- AwesomeList::SmartPointer::~SmartPointer() + 21 (awesomelist.h:22)

Any help is appreciate. Thanks!

UPDATE

I solved my problem changing SmartPointer and Nodo classes like this:

```
SmartPointer(Nodo* n = 0): punt(n) {
        if (punt) punt->references++;
    }
    SmartPointer(const SmartPointer& ptr): punt(ptr.punt) {
        if (punt) punt->references++;
    }
    ~SmartPointer() {
        if (punt) {
            punt->references--;
            if (punt->references == 0) delete punt;
        }
    }

    SmartPointer& operator=(const SmartPointer& ptr) {
        if (this != &ptr) {
            Nodo* n = punt;
            punt = ptr.punt;
            if (punt) punt->references++;
            if (n) {
                n->references--;
                if (n->references == 0) delete n;
            }
        }
        return *this;
    }
    bool operator==(const SmartPointer& ptr) const {
        return ptr.punt == punt;
    }
    bool operator!=(const SmartPointer& ptr) const {
        return ptr.punt != punt;
    }
    Nodo* operator->() const {
        return punt;
    }
    Nodo& operator*() const {
        return *punt;
    }
};

class Nodo {
public:
    T* value;
    SmartPointer next;
    int references;

    Nodo(T* t = T(), const SmartPointer& ptr = SmartPointer()): value(t), next(ptr), references(0) {}
};
```

Comment: Your error list doesn't actually list what the errors are...

Comment: The error is EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Comment: My friend, I think you are trying to fool us. `SmartPointer head;` cannot be compiled with only a forward declaration of `SmartPointer`. You need the full definition of  `SmartPointer` to instantiate a `SmartPointer`.

Comment: Nodo is clearly supposed to be a template, but is not declared as one. Methinks you dropped the `template<class T>` ahead of `class AwesomeList`

Comment: @user4581301, the program compiles, don't worry. I asked help for the error EXC_BAD_ACCESS. template <class T> is present. I have not included in the message because it created problems.

Comment: If the code compiles, you are doing something else that you aren't showing. To allocate storage for `head`, the size of `SmartPointer` must be available. It won't be available for another 30-or-so lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry but I don't understand the ratio beneath your `SmartPointer` class.

It carry a pointer to a `Nodo` and `delete` it with the constructor. Good.

But, if I'm not wrong

(1) when you create a `SmartPointer` with copy constructor, you copy the pointer from the `SmartPointer` copied so you have two object with a `punt` with the same value; when you destroy the two objects, you call `delete` two times over the same pointer; this can crash the program

(2) when you call `operator=`, you have the same problem with the copy constructor but, moreover, you don't delete the old pointed value

By example, look at `add()`

```
    head = SmartPointer(new Nodo(&(const_cast<T&>(t))));
    tail = head;
```

You create a temporary `SmartPointer` object initializing it with `new Nodo(&(const_cast<T&>(t)))`. Next you copy this temporary object in `head`, so both `head` and the temporary object are carrying the same not-NULL pointer. Now the temporary object is destroyed, so the memory pointed by `punt` is deleted but `head` (his `punt`) continue to point to a memory area that is deleted. Now you copy `head` in `tail`, and you have both `head` and `tail` that are pointing to the same deleted area.

Look at the else case

```
    tail->next = SmartPointer(new Nodo(&(const_cast<T&>(t))));
    tail = tail->next;
```

In this case, `tail->next` (and take in count that `take` point to a deleted area) receive a pointer from a temporary object that delete it. So you write in a deleted area a pointer that is immediately deleted.

I hope it is clear how much all this is dangerous.

Suggestion: redesign `SmartPointer` class.

p.s.: sorry for my bad English.

Comment: You have been very cleared. Thanks! In your opinion, if I use a private field SmartPointer* head, and then I write head = new SmartPointer(...), could solve my problem?

Comment: Think on the logic of that for a moment. You want to create a raw pointer to a smart pointer. This defeats the point of the smart pointer. Max is correct. You need to re-implement `SmartPointer`, make it [rule of 5 compliant](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three), and [use move semantics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/what-are-move-semantics). An alternative is [use `std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) instead of `SmartPointer`.

Comment: Yes, you right. Any suggestion? PS:I've update my code with a correct operator=.

Comment: @ Daniele - Yes, checking if you're copying a object on itself is good. But the main problem remain: you can have multiple instances of `SmartPointer` with the same value for `punt` and, so, you risk to delete two or more time the same pointer.

Comment: @Daniele - I suppose you're developing this code to make practice with C++ (otherwise, my suggestion is: use `std::list` and, if you can use C++11, `std::shared_ptr`) so I suggest (just to play with C++): add a counter in `Nodo` and initialize it to zero; every time you copy a `Nodo` pointer to a `SmartPointer`, increment the counter in the node pointed; every time you release a pointer from a `SmartPointe` (destructor and old value in assignment operator), decrement the node counter and verify the value; call `delete` only when the counter (post decrement) is zero. Just to play with C++.